# org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException

Tags: java, spring

I am working in spring3 project. When I run my code sometimes i am getting this Jdbc Connection Exception for some particular functionality but other functionalities working very fine. And also this Exception is not occurring repetitively but sometimes, So I can't get where the mistake will be.
Please help me to come out of this problem.

> <[weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext@1b6e978 - appName:  '_auto_generated_ear_', name: 'ae', context-path: '/ae'] Root cause of ServletException.
>    org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
>   ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found
>   The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
>   localhost:1521:XE at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:573)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:637)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:666)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:674)
>       Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>   java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
>   ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found
>   The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
>   localhost:1521:XE
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:261)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:420)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:165)
>       Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Comment: I guess too many connections were opened ! Have you deployed the app in multiple JVMs ?

Comment: @The New Idiot thank u for the response. I will check the connections

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 2 common reason for that symptoms

- The connection pool is exhausted, too many active connections open and the next client cannot get it. This might be a connection pool leak
- The connection pool setting doesn't test idle connection periodically / on borrow, hence when TCP connection truncated by OS (eg: because the OS thinks it's idle doing nothing), the pool still thinks it's a valid

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, just **Restart your MySQL service**

**How to restart the MySQL service** 
On Windows: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-adminsitration/restart-mysql 
On Linux:    https://linuxhint.com/restart-mysql-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227)